# Sass sourcemap working directly but not working for localhost on Chromium

Tags: css, gulp, chromium, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I am running Debian Wheezy. I am playing with gulp last few days. My problem is that when I point browser to file directly (file:///...) source maps linked correctly like this:

[image: file:///...]

But when I point with localhost/... I get this:

[image: localhost/...]

On Iceweasel everything works perfectly. I triple checked all settings, so that part is OK. I thought it might be some security issue, so I chmod recursively project root, but that is not the issue.

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

This is my gulpfile.js:

[image: This is my gulpfile.js]

I got scss files that look like this:

index.scss

[image: index.scss]

_test.scss

[image: _test.scss]

When I run gulp command on root folder I get:

index.css

[image: index.css]

Can it be some Chromium issue? I tried doing almost everything I could think of. The fact that it's working on Iceweasel makes me think it's specific Chromium problem, but it's so hard to give up. :D

Comment: Do you get any 404? Are you running it from a server or via the file:// protocol?

Comment: @ddprrt, I don't get any 404s. The thing is when I run via file:// protocol source maps do their work correctly, but when I go to http://localhost, they don't. This is the issue for Chromium only, thou. There is no problem with source maps on Iceweasel.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the similar issue, especially with `BrowserSync`.

### Version Info:

OS X El Capitan@10.11.12

Google Chrome@47.0.2526.80 (64-bit)

browser-sync@2.9.0

### Description

Chrome could not autoload `Scss sourcemaps` watched by `BrowserSync`, while Chrome private mode, Chrome Canary, Safari works with `Scss sourcemaps` correctly whether using `BrowserSync` or [python simple HTTP server command line](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/).

The solution may be specific to my case. I tried Google Web Starter Kit(@0.6.0)'s `Service-Worker` previously, so I went to `chrome://serviceworker-internals` and unregistered items listed in that page.

It's done. `Soucemaps` work as expected again.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your local folder in chrome workspace. Here is a perfect tutorial on enabling and using workspaces:

http://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure that all your answers to questions contain sufficient information to stand on their own; if your answer relies exclusively on links to other sites, it won't be useful should that link fail to load.